# Transient Analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis, transient

I'm given this circuit and I have to calculate V1 as a function of time:

[image]

It is given that V1 at t=0 is Vdd. So the steady state solution will just be V1 = Vdd. I'm having trouble finding the homogeneous solution. I converted the circuit to be more visually sensible:

[image]

I then did KVL around the first loop and got to:
[image]

I'm kinda stuck at this point. The orientation and arrangement of everything is throwing me off. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
convert source \$V_{dd}\$ with voltage divider \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ to its Thevenin Equivalent (\$V_{th} = V_{dd}\frac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2}\$, \$R_{th} = R_1 || R_2\$).

The circuit then becomes very simple:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYqZh2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: OP, just as Curd's said, it's (a) find Thevenin equivalent to produce R-C circuit (b) adapt the R-C charging equation to this circuit. It's more straightforward than it might appear to you, stick with it. Good luck :-)

Comment: I used to do Thevenin when the load was the capacitor and all the other components were resistors. It's been a good year since I did all that but I remember doing the equivalent resistance for Rth and then doing Voltage of open circuit to get Vth. But here I'm not measuring the voltage across the capacitor like I used to do but rather across R2 so I guess that's what's throwing me off.

Comment: I guess my question is, what is the load for the Thevenin equivalent? The capacitor or R2?

Comment: See my edit: a Thevenin source is a voltage source with series resistor. So there's only C left to be the load.